# Level curves and sketch of (x-a)*(y-b) type functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

While doing exercises in level curves I ran across these two functions which I couldn't get my head around.
The functions are:

1. $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=0$

Here showing graphs of YZ-plane and XZ-plane sections is easy, they are just parabolas facing downwards, but obviously this is not a paraboloid, so I'm at a loss here.

2. $(x-1)(y+1)(z+2)=0$

I don't even have an idea how to start this one.

Comment: The first represents four planes and the second is three planes $x=1,y=-1$ and $z=-2$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomLyden You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **first** case we have

$$(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=0 \implies (x^2-1)=0 \quad \lor \quad (y^2-1)=0 $$
$$\implies x=1 \quad \lor \quad x=-1 \quad \lor \quad  y=1 \quad \lor \quad y=-1$$

which represent for planes (and their intersection lines).

For the **second** case we have

$$(x-1)(y+1)(z+2)=0 $$
$$\implies x=1 \quad \lor \quad y=-1 \quad \lor \quad  z=-2$$

which represent three planes (and their intersection lines).